# SQL Date Exclusion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of SQL selects that collect data for export and analysis.  I have declared the date range I want to collect the data for in a couple of variables and run the query, there are 10 selects total that use the same date range variables.  What I would like to do is easily exclude certain dates (they are single days rather than a range) from the query using some sort of exclusion list that I can declare in a variable so all my selects remove those particular dates rather than editing every select statement.

```
DECLARE @date_start DATETIME, @date_end DATETIME
SET @date_start = '2011-10-20 00:00:00'
SET @date_end = '2012-05-18 23:59:59'

SELECT
date, col1, col2, col3
FROM
table1
WHERE
date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @date_start, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @date_end, 102)

SELECT
date, col4, col5, col8
FROM
table2
WHERE
date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @date_start, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @date_end, 102)

SELECT
date, col3, col5, col6, col7, col8
FROM
table3
WHERE
date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @date_start, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @date_end, 102)
```

Comment: Why are you `CONVERT`ing dates to dates?

Comment: It's usually better when working with date ranges in SQL Server to use `>=` and `<` rather than `between`. This lets you use more reasonable representations, and avoids a current issue that you're missing anything that happens during the last second of the interval (e.g. at `2012-05-18T23:59:59.003`).

Comment: It's a legacy/lazy thing, the data types on some of the date columns I was using were not actually datetime in the database, it's a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Use IN:

Append this to your query: AND date not in (date1,date2...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN in the where condition to specify the selected dates. and also when you are considering only date part better use Convert(varchar,datecolumn,111) which gives yyyy/MM/dd format. No need to give time part 23:59:59.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table variable with the dates you are looking for and use that in the query.

You can build that table using your date range variables and another table that holds the dates you are not looking for.

Something like this:

```
declare @date_start datetime
declare @date_end datetime

-- The date range you want. Don't add time part.
set @date_start = '20010102'
set @date_end = '20010107'

declare @NotTheDatesYouAreLookingFor as table
(
  date datetime
)

insert into @NotTheDatesYouAreLookingFor values
('20010103'),
('20010105')

declare @TheDatesYouAreLookingFor as table
(
  date datetime primary key
)

;with C(date) as
(
  select @date_start
  union all
  select date + 1
  from C
  where date < @date_end
)
insert into @TheDatesYouAreLookingFor(date)
select date
from C
  where date not in (select date 
                     from @NotTheDatesYouAreLookingFor)
```

And your queries should use the table `@TheDatesYouAreLookingFor` like this.

```
select T1.date, T1.col1, T1.col2, T1.col3
from table1 as T1
  inner join @TheDatesYouAreLookingFor as TD
    on T1.date >= TD.date and T1.date < dateadd(day, 1, TD.date)
```